# Kotlin object, an implementation vs instance

Tags: kotlin, instance

In [Objects in Kotlin: Create safe singletons in one line of code (KAD 27)](https://antonioleiva.com/objects-kotlin/) Antonio Leiva states:

> In fact, an object is just a data type with a single **implementation**.

I would expect to see the term *instance* rather than *implementation* used here. Is there some nuance that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does have a single instance after all, but I believe what they meant to say is that whatever you write in an object is `final` and you can not override it. Even if you make it open(for argument purpose), you can not make an anonymous object out of it since the anonymous class can't be used on a SingleTon instance.

So " data type with a single implementation" means, whatever you write is the final implementation. An instance is, after all, a result of some implementation.

For reference, I am adding a decompiled code of `object` declaration.

```
public final class Test {
  @NotNull
  private static final String testMember = "Test";
  public static final Test INSTANCE;

 @NotNull
 public final String getTestMember() {
   return testMember;
 }

 private Test() {
 }
   static {
    Test var0 = new Test();
    INSTANCE = var0;
    testMember = "Test";
  }
}
```